# Simplest 'true' value that the compiler doesn't recognise as true

Tags: c#, if-statement, compiler-warnings

I had a little debug intercept that said

```
if (true)
    throw new Exception()
DoStuff();
```

However the compiler warned me that DoStuff() was unreachable code. So were the following:

```
if (1==1)
if (1 + 1 == 2)
```

The following 'works'

```
int x = 1;
if (2 * x == 2)
    throw...
```

What expression is obviously true to a human yet not to the compiler? The best I could manage was

```
bool False =>false;
if (False)
```

...and it has the wonderful property that to switch it off all I have to do is change it to

```
bool False=>true  /*  :D)     */
```

Comment: You are seeing a difference between the analysis of constant expressions and the analysis of expressions that are not constant.  If this is C# the analysis will assume `x` may contain any valid int value when it does flow analysis. (`bool False=>true` is likely to get you arrested)

Comment: This sounds like a situations where you should just let the compiler warn you. Who cares? You're doing something weird anyway.

Comment: You should probably check the [Debug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug(v=vs.110).aspx) class and trace switches. .NET allows you to break based on build types and conditions since 1.0. The humble `Debug.Assert(false)` breaks on Debug but gets removed on release builds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to mess up your code, you can do this:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]
void stop() { throw new Exception(); }
```

To have a method which exists in `Debug` but doesn't exist in `Release`, used normally:

```
void MyMethod()
{
    stop(); // If you're in Release, this invocation will be removed
    DoStuff();
}
```

I do it all the time in my pieces of code, with my methods following the naming convention `DebugConditional_CopyPasteOfContainerName()`

Comment: `Debug.Assert(false);` ?